# Angular stop making api request after given milliseconds even if it's not succeeded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to fetch status from backend until the condition is met but I don't want to overload server by making request forever :) .I want to stop making request after one minute.
here is the code

```
  this.statusService
.getStatus(this.itemId).pipe(
repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(500))),
filter(data => {
  if(data.status === 'done'){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
   }),
take(1)
).subscribe(result =>{
  console.log(‘done')
});
```

I tried timeout() but it doesn't stop making request

```
  this.statusService
.getStatus(this.itemId).pipe(
 timeout(60000),
repeatWhen(obs => obs.pipe(delay(500))),
filter(data => {
  if(data.status === 'done'){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
   }),
take(1)
).subscribe(result =>{
  console.log(‘done')
});
```

Comment: Your timeout is currently set for 1m and 40 seconds. For a minute you need to input timeout(60000)

Comment: @Jahrenski I think that's not the solution but I updated that :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

One simple solution can be:

```
const apiCall$ = this.statusService.getStatus(this.itemId)
  .pipe(
    delay(1000),
    repeat(),
    filter(data => (data.status === 'done'))
  );

const timeout$ = of(false).pipe(delay(3000));

// The observable to emit first is used
race([apiCall$, timeout$])
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: In this case there will be no delay between each request

Comment: Just put delay operator on the top, i updated my post so you can try it.

Comment: Thanks it works . is it possible to trigger message when condition is not met after a minute ?

Comment: You meant to get a value in subscribe function? With what value?

Comment: Yes in subscribe function. I mean if status is 'done' within one minute I will show success message other wise I want to show error message for example 'please try later'

Comment: I updated the example, if condition is met, result will be true. I after a certain time condition is not met, result will be false.

Comment: Thanks it's working :)